Queue monitoring oracle script
I am trying to monitor a queues on a dashboard.
I want my select to return something even if the queue table is empty, look at my current qry.
SELECT 'QueueName' Q_NAME,
       CASE 
       WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 
       THEN (SELECT 'Nothing to process Queue is empty' FROM DUAL)
       ELSE 'something in the Queue'
       END Q_STATUS,
       CASE
       WHEN MSG_STATE = 'READY' AND MIN(ENQ_TIME) > SYSDATE - 5/(24*60)
       THEN 'OK: processing'
       ELSE 'Nothing to process on Queue'
       END STATUS
FROM   QueueTable
GROUP BY MSG_STATE;


Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; details of the issue/error with your current query; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment, your post does not include a question or an explanation of what you expect the output to be which makes it impossible to answer.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't understand... what's the question?

COUNT(*) = 0 is never going to be true when you have a GROUP BY clause - if there is nothing to count in a group then that group will be omitted.

If you question is:

How can I return a row when the table is empty?

Then you can use UNION ALL to add another row with the defaults for an empty table and then order the rows by priority, with Queue detail rows having higher priority that the default row, and output only the highest priority rows:
SELECT Q_Name, Q_Status, Status
FROM   (
  SELECT 'QueueName' AS Q_NAME,
         CASE 
         WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 
         THEN 'Nothing to process Queue is empty'
         ELSE 'something in the Queue'
         END AS Q_STATUS,
         CASE
         WHEN MSG_STATE = 'READY' AND MIN(ENQ_TIME) > SYSDATE - 5/(24*60)
         THEN 'OK: processing'
         ELSE 'Nothing to process on Queue'
         END AS STATUS,
         1 AS priority
  FROM   QueueTable
  GROUP BY MSG_STATE
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'QueueName',
         'Nothing to process Queue is empty',
         'Nothing to process on Queue',
         2
  FROM   DUAL
)
ORDER BY priority
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;

Which, for the sample empty table:
CREATE TABLE QueueTable (msg_state VARCHAR2(10), enq_time DATE);

Outputs:



Q_NAME
Q_STATUS
STATUS




QueueName
Nothing to process Queue is empty
Nothing to process on Queue




Note: When using a GROUP BY clause, COUNT(*) = 0 will never be true as you cannot have a group with zero rows (as the group does not exist).
So your query can be simplified to:
SELECT Q_Name, Q_Status, Status
FROM   (
  SELECT 'QueueName' AS Q_NAME,
         'something in the Queue' AS Q_STATUS,
         CASE
         WHEN MSG_STATE = 'READY'
         AND  MIN(ENQ_TIME) > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
         THEN 'OK: processing'
         ELSE 'Nothing to process on Queue'
         END AS STATUS,
         1 AS priority
  FROM   QueueTable
  GROUP BY MSG_STATE
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'QueueName',
         'Nothing to process Queue is empty',
         'Nothing to process on Queue',
         2
  FROM   DUAL
)
ORDER BY priority
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;

fiddle

This is what I am looking for, thank you. Quite a lot to learn.
